# Datatable not scrolling

Tags: jquery, css, datatables

I am attempting to make my datatable scroll horizontally so if using a mobile device or small screen all the info in the table can be seen. At the moment it just shows what it can then the rest is hidden.

I have played around with some css / jquery to try fix the issue but still not getting any scrolling on the table.

Table html:

```
<div class="module-body">
                        <div class="module">
                            <div class="module-head">
                                <h3>Entries</h3>
                            </div>
                            <div class="module-body table">
                                <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" class="datatable-1 table table-bordered table-striped display" width="100%" id="members">
                                    <thead>
                                        <tr>
                                            <th>Date Entered</th>
                                            <th>Driver</th>
                                            <th>Member No</th>
                                            <th>Class</th>
                                            <th>Age</th>
                                            <th>Lady</th>
                                            <th>Navigator</th>
                                            <th>Member No</th>
                                            <th>Class</th>
                                            <th>Age</th>
                                            <th>Lady</th>
                                            <th>Make / Model</th>
                                            <th>Registration</th>
                                            <th>Running Class</th>

                                            <th></th>
                                        </tr>
                                    </thead>
                                     <?php
//MySqli Select Query
$results = $mysqli->query("SELECT *, DATE_FORMAT(date,'%d/%m/%Y %h %m') AS niceDate  FROM entries WHERE sevent='$id'");



//set counter
while($row = $results->fetch_assoc()) {
            $compid = $row["id"];





  echo'
                                         <tr>
                                         <td><span class="hide">'.$row["date"].'</span>'.$row["niceDate"].'</td>     
                                         <td>'.$row["dname"].'</td>
                                          <td>'.$row["dmno"].'</td>
                                           <td>'.$row["dclass"].'</td>
                                            <td>'.$row["dage"].'</td>
                                          <td>'.$row["dlady"].'</td>
                                          <td>'.$row["nname"].'</td>
                                          <td>'.$row["nmno"].'</td>
                                           <td>'.$row["nclass"].'</td>
                                            <td>'.$row["nage"].'</td>
                                          <td>'.$row["nlady"].'</td>
                                          <td>'.$row["make"].' '.$row["model"].'</td>
                                            <td>'.$row["reg"].'</td>
                                          <td>'.$row["nclass"].'</td>




                                             <td align="center" valign="middle"><a href="editcomp.php?id='.$compid.'">Edit Competitor</a></td>
                                             </tr>
                                             ';




}  


?> 
                                </table>
                            </div>
                            </div>
                            </div>
                            </div>
```

I have tried putting `overflow: auto;`

I have tried

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#members').DataTable( {
        "scrollX": true
    } );
} );
```

Why isn't the table scrolling horizontally with any of the above. How can I make it scroll?

Comment: has overflow:hidden; been applied to an upper level element? Like the body or wrapper or something.

Comment: @CarolMcKay not what I can find.

Comment: your table has a class "datatable-1" it does not have a class "DataTable"

Comment: so if I was to update it to <script>
  
   $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#members').dataTable-1( {
        "scrollX": true
    } );
} );

</script> that should work? Tried that and it doesn't do anything?

Answer (score 0):

Try doing this

div class="module-body table"  style="overflow-x: scroll;overflow-y: hidden;">

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
<div class="module-body table"
style="max-width:80vw; overflow-x:auto">
```